# Moq - What is Range in It.IsInRange(TValue from, TValue to, Range rangeKind)?

Tags: moq

I've searched google for an explanation of what the Range parameter does but found nothing, so I'm putting my trust in you to explain what the difference is in setting Range.Inclusive or Range.Exclusive when using `It.IsInRange(TValue from, TValue to, Range rangeKind)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know for sure, but I would assume that inclusive means that the values that you provide for the range are part of the range and exclusive means that they are not part of the range:

inclusive:   lower bound <= x <= upper bound

exclusive:   lower bound <  x <  upper bound

Answer (score 5):

The Range (Enum) parameter as specified in the [documentation](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/Range) -

```
Exclusive :     The range does not include the to and from values.
Inclusive :     The range includes the to and from values.
```

Usage as the answer demonstrates

```
It.IsInRange(0, 100, Range.Exclusive); // will not match for int values 0 and 100, but matches 1 to 99
```

and

```
It.IsInRange(0, 100, Range.Inclusive); // will match for int values 0 and 100, and in-between
```